# Remote debugging in flink

Tags: java, jvm, apache-flink, remote-debugging

Added one parameter in flink-conf.yaml :

```
env.java.opts.taskmanager: "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=51005"
```

Then i started a jobmanager and a taskmanager using below commands on localhost :

```
flink-1.9.1_bin/bin/jobmanager.sh start
flink-1.9.1_bin/bin/taskmanager.sh start
```

Jobmanager runs and i can see flink UI dashboard on localhost:8081. Taskmanager waits for connection on 51001 port. It runs after i debug my code from IDE(IntelliJ) which has setup for remote debugging on localhost:51001. I can see tasks slots been added when i start debugging from IDE. After this i ran below command:

```
flink-1.9.1_bin/bin/flink run -c myapp.Main myapp.jar
```

I am expecting debug point to come to my local code in IDE, but it's not coming. My code goes in running state directly that i can in flink UI dashboard.

I am able do remote debugging for normal java projects but not for flink jobs.

Answer (score 0):

The mainClass in myapp.jar represents the job definition and is executed when bin/flink run is invoked. To enable remote debugging, add JVM options to the bin/flink script.

If you want to debug the data flow within the job, include JVM options for the TaskManager and add breakpoints to the Deserializer or other code responsible for processing data when the job receives input.